# Copy sent emails to Sent folder (email server)

Tags: powershell

I have a working script in PowerShell to send emails.
I need to know how to put a copy of my sent emails in Sent folder on mail server.

```
$EmailTo = "you@email.com"
$Subject = "Subject"
$EmailFrom = "me@email.com"
$Body = Get-Content -Path body.html
$SMTPServer = "mail.email.com"
$SMTPMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage ($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body)
$SMTPMessage.IsBodyHTML = $true
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient ($SmtpServer, 25)
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $False
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential ("me@email.com", "password");
$SMTPClient.Send($SMTPMessage)
```

Comment: That is an MUA feature. Simple SMTP clients like `Net.Mail.SmtpClient` don't provide this. As a workaround you could add a BCC to yourself/the sender.

Comment: Thank you Ansgar. Can you help me based on provided code?

Comment: I already did, didn't I?

Comment: Yes. Never mind. I solve the problem. Thank you again.